# How to redirect naked domain to www with Cloudfront?

Tags: amazon-web-services, redirect, dns, amazon-cloudfront

I have a website hosted on AWS Cloudfront but my domain is registered with "101 Domain". I've successfully pointed the www CNAME to the cloudfront instance domain, so when accessing my site with "www" it works. Unfortunately, 101Domains only allows the Alias record for the naked domain to point to an IP Address, however cloudfront does not provide one.

I'm fine with my site redirecting to "www" but unable to implement this. What's the best approach to resolve this?

Comment: Register your domain to use route 53

Comment: Route53 charges, you can use cloudflare dns basic plan which is free and they allow you to create something call cname flattening for naked domain which is same as Route53 alias record.

Answer (score 0):

As both of your **Amazon CloudFront** and **EC2 instance** are belonged to AWS.

Why don't give it a try for **Amazon Route 53**? which costs for 0.5$ a month for private DNS.

1) Create a new hosted zone:

```
mydomain.com
```

2) Update the NS which are provided from "101 Domain". This step will take a while.

```
mydomain.com     |   NS  | <update 4 provided NS from 101 Domain>
```

*You can confirm if the change has been made as follows:*

```
nslookup mydomain.com
```

3) Refer to the configuration below:

```
www.mydomain.com | CNAME | mydomain.com
mydomain.com     |   A   | alias <yours>.cloudfront.net
```

Comment: Since I'm using a ".app" domain, it doesn't seem that Amazon Route 53 is an option for me.

Comment: setting A record to point to CloudFront says invalid entry.

Comment: @Nithur Have you used A (with Alias) or A instead? My example is related to Route53 setup, for others, it is CNAME instead :D

Comment: Alias is the right way to point the apex domain to Cloudfront in Route53. From other services we can't point apex domain since we can only add CNAME.

Answer (score 0):

After *a lot* of time spent on this, I've finally reached a solution that works. I'm using a 3rd party service to do the forwarding for me (thanks nakedssl.com!). I know it's technically cheating, but it works.

I know many mentioned Amazon Route 53, but since I'm using a ".app" domain name, that's not an option for me unfortunately.